# "DateTime->modify('+0 days')" Modifies DateTime Object

Tags: php, datetime

Could anyone elaborate on why the following `DateTime->modify()` code yields those weird contradicting results, depending on the PHP version (is it a bug ? In which PHP version ?).

I would expect all examples to produce the same date and time the objects were created with, but this is apparently not the case.

The only example that seems to work is the one in the middle where the `DateTime` object is created from a UNIX timestamp and where the time zone is set afterwards (it cannot be set upon construction because that will be ignored).

PHP 5.4.4 and 5.4.6:

```
FROM TIMESTAMP, NO TZ:
2012-08-21 22:00:00 GMT+0000 (offset 0)  <-- different 
2012-08-21 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (offset 0)  <-- from this
FROM TIMESTAMP, WITH TZ:
2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST (offset 7200)
2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST (offset 7200)
FROM STRING:
2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST (offset 7200)
2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST (offset 7200)
```

PHP 5.2.0:

```
FROM TIMESTAMP, NO TZ:
2012-08-21 22:00:00 GMT+0100 (offset 7200)
2012-08-21 22:00:00 GMT+0100 (offset 7200)
FROM TIMESTAMP, WITH TZ:
2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST (offset 7200)
2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST (offset 7200)
FROM STRING:
2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST (offset 7200)  <-- different
2012-08-21 23:00:00 CEST (offset 7200)  <-- from this
```

Code:

```
<?php
  $tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');

  echo "FROM TIMESTAMP, NO TZ:\n";

  $date = new DateTime('@'.strtotime('2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST'));
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T').' (offset '.$date->getOffset().")\n";

  $date->modify('+0 days');
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T').' (offset '.$date->getOffset().")\n";

  echo "FROM TIMESTAMP, WITH TZ:\n";

  $date = new DateTime('@'.strtotime('2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST'));
  $date->setTimezone($tz);
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T').' (offset '.$date->getOffset().")\n";

  $date->modify('+0 days');
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T').' (offset '.$date->getOffset().")\n";

  echo "FROM STRING:\n";

  $date = new DateTime('2012-08-22 00:00:00 CEST', $tz);
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T').' (offset '.$date->getOffset().")\n";

  $date->modify('+0 days');
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T').' (offset '.$date->getOffset().")\n";
?>
```

Comment: I can confirm this behavior using `PHP 5.4.4` on `Windows` (using a `Europe/Berlin` timezone)

Comment: I confirm too using PHP 5.3.8 on Ubuntu, same behavior, actually if you `$date->modify('+1 hour');` it will output expected result.

Comment: Note: Using `DateTime::add()` and specifying an appropriate `DateInterval "P0D"` doesn't change the date. I think it's a bug in PHP, please be so kind and report it.

Comment: @DanielM, Yeah, I was searching the bug database for it already and will probably report it now. Seems to affect both Linux and Windows versions alike. Also confirmed with latest Windows snapshot from August 22, 3:27 pm, r4e56105.

Comment: 5.3.15 doesn't seem to exhibit this behaviour; the changelog shows a bunch of fixes since 5.3.9, perhaps those weren't all migrated to 5.4

Comment: @Daniel, suggest you submit that as an answer so we can upvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DateTime::add()` and specifying an appropriate `DateInterval "P0D"` doesn't change the date. I think it's a bug in PHP, please be so kind and report it.